# Make two horizontal textviews stay left if together they are less than a certain width, but ellipsize left view if they'll be longer than the width?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

The behavior I am looking for is below. Imagine the the brackets, [], are the same size of `max_width`.

1. when `text1` and `text2` combined is less than `max_width`, say 100dp:

   [text1short text2short --empty space-- ]
2. when `text1` and `text2` combined is greater than `max_width`, text1 is ellipsized:

   [text1sho... text2loooooooooooooooong]

Here's what I have so far, and it works, but is there a way to use only one layout to accomplish this?

```
<FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/container"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/max_width"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/some_height">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:maxLines="1" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:maxLines="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking into `ConstraintLayout` and `Guidelines` for this.

Answer (score 0):

[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) is the way to go. Below is a layout that does what you need. There are some key *ConstraintLayout* concepts incorporated into this layout such as chains and guidelines. The chain with the constrained width widget is key. The guideline is less important to this layout and is just a way to constrain how far the *TextViews* can spread.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Short left view."
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Short right"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvLeft"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvLeft" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="300dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the layout with short content:

[image]

And with long content in the left TextView:

[image]

The images are from the Android Studio layout designer.

Comment: Thanks Cheticamp, I ended up using something quite similar to your solution, but without the Guideline. I used a packed chain style constraint layout, and added `layout_constraintWidth_default=wrap` for the text1 textfield, which worked well. I found it in this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#adjust-the-view-size

Answer (score 0):

I used a packed chain style constraint layout, and added `layout_constraintWidth_default=wrap` for the text1 textfield, which worked well. I found it in this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#adjust-the-view-size

```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text1"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/some_height"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:maxLines="1"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text2"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thing_on_the_left"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/some_height"
      android:maxLines="1"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/thing_on_the_right"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text1"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```